# grails h2 database create table

Tags: database, grails, h2

I have a really simple domain class

```
class Person {

  String code

}
```

And I am also using default DataSource configuration:

```
dataSource {
  pooled = true
  driverClassName = "org.h2.Driver"
  username = "sa"
  password = ""
}
hibernate {
  cache.use_second_level_cache = true
  cache.use_query_cache = false
  cache.region.factory_class = 'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory'
}
// environment specific settings
environments {
  development {
    dataSource {
      dbCreate = "create-drop" // one of 'create', 'create-drop', 'update', 'validate', ''
      url = "jdbc:h2:mem:devDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000"
      dialect = "org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect"
    }
  } ...
```

But when I open /dbconsole then I see that DB is empty and there is no tables. Why? What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you open the `dbconsole` you have to make sure its reading the correct database.

In your url section, point the dbconsole to the url that your app is using. In your case:

```
jdbc:h2:mem:devDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000
```

Answer (score 0):

My project i am using mysql and my datasource looks like

```
dataSource {
    pooled = true
    driverClassName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    loggingSql = false
    properties {
        validationQuery="select 1"
        testWhileIdle=true
        timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis=60000
    }
}
hibernate {
    cache.use_second_level_cache = false
    cache.use_query_cache = false
    cache.provider_class = 'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheProvider'
    generate_statistics = false
}
// environment specific settings
environments {
    development {
    dataSource {
        dbCreate = "update" // one of 'create', 'create-drop','update'
        url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/my_db"
        username="XXX"
        password="XXXXXX"
    }

    }       


}
```

And this configuration is working fine

Answer (score 0):

If you are running Grails in development mode and make changes I believe they will not be committed to the H2 database if the default settings are in place. You would need to run the app in production mode or change some configuration properties to view the updated information in DBConsole.
[Similar StackOverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3268421/confusion-with-grails-development-database)